# Replicating TF model in Keras from pbtxt and ckpts

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I'm not sure if this is actually possible with the information I have, but please let me know if that's the case.

From a previously trained Tensorflow model I have the following files:

`graph.pbtxt`, `checkpoint`, `model.ckpt-10000.data-00000-of-00001`, `model.ckpt-10000.index`, and `model.ckpt-10000.meta`

I was told that the input size of this model was a Dense layer of size `5000` and the output was a Dense sigmoid binary classification, but I don't know how many/what size layers were in between. (I'm also not 100% positive that the input size is correct).

From this information and associated files, is there a way to replicate the TF model with trained weights into a Keras functional model?

(The idea was that this small dense network was added onto the last FC layer of VGG-16, so that'll be my end goal.)